# Is it possible to get name of pydantic field as string?

Tags: python, pydantic

```py
class Settings(BaseSettings):
    SITE_URL: str

CONFIG = Settings()

>>> CONFIG.SITE_URL
```

returns str, and that's expected

Is it possible somehow to get access to dotted string representation of field?

`CONFIG.SITE_URL.__some_magic_attr_ == 'CONFIG.SITE_URL'`

Answer (score 1):

Once initialized, the attribute of a Pydantic model is simply of the type that was defined for it. In this case `SITE_URL` is just a string. Thus, there is no special magic method, to get its field name.

Depending on your actual use case though, the [`__fields__`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#model-properties) attribute of the model might be useful. It is a dictionary mapping field names to the `ModelField` objects. For example

```py
from pydantic import BaseSettings

class Settings(BaseSettings):
    SITE_URL: str

print(Settings.__fields__['SITE_URL'])
```

gives

```
name='SITE_URL' type=str required=True
```

If you have your settings object, you can for example do this:

```py
for name in CONFIG.__fields__.keys():
    print(f'{CONFIG.__class__.__name__}.{name}')
```

giving you

```
Settings.SITE_URL
...
```

If you want the name of the variable storing your settings object, I assume you can just write it as a string manually, i.e.

```py
for name in CONFIG.__fields__.keys():
    print(f'CONFIG.{name}')
```